# Countable discontinuities and pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$ and each $\{f_n\}$ has a countable number of discontinuities, what is a counterexample to $f$ also having a countable number of discontinuities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\{a_i\}$ be an enumeration of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and let $f_n$ be defined on $[0,1]$ so that 
$$f_n(x) = \textbf{1}_{\{a_i : i<n\}}$$ which converges pointwise to $\textbf{1}_{[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}}(x)$ and is discontinuous on all of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I would think that function has $ \mathbb{Q} $ discontinuities which is countable, why does it instead have a discontinuity at every real in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: @Salamander No, it's discontinuous at every real in $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $[0,1]$,for any $x_0 \in [0,1]$ and any neighbourhood $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ we can see that $f$ is jumping between $1$ and $0$, hence no continuity.